# Returning Functions value as Mysql result

Tags: php, sql

i have a problem. I want to return a Function's value as a mysql result

```
function Gets_comments_array_from_db($type, $thread_comment_id) {
# Sets variable for Query
    $The_TYPE = $type;
    $Thread = mysql_real_escape_string(intval($thread_comment_id));

# return array query for Further working
    return mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `site_comments` WHERE `type`='".$The_TYPE."' AND `thread_comment_id`='".$Thread."'");
```

}

And

```
while($comment = mysql_fetch_array(Gets_comments_array_from_db('news', $id)){
                                                    echo '11';
                                                }
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Why do you wonder that this does not function properly? You are executing `Gets_comments_array_from_db` on every first iteration in the while loop, so you are executing the query over and over again .. only getting the first result .. if any. And why do you want to do this anyway? So pointless ..

Comment: Do you iterate $id somewhere as well...?

Answer (score 0):

As **dbf** said you are executing the query every iteration of the while loop.  You need to change the code like this:

```
$rs = Gets_comments_array_from_db('news', $id);

while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
     echo '11';
}
```

Now you will get the results one time then iterate through them in the while loop.  Also inside the loop you will be able to work with the values using the column names as the array keys.

```
while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
     $field1 = $comment['field1'];
     $field2 = $comment['field2'];
     $field3 = $comment['field3'];
}
```

If you structure your mysql query like this

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 FROM {table} WHERE {where_clause}
```

you will be able to set your variables in while loop like this

```
$rs = Gets_comments_array_from_db('news', $id);

while(list($field1, $filed2, $filed3, $field4) = myslq_fetch_row($rs)) {
    // use variables here
}
```